# Call to a member function get_method_id() on bool

Tags: wordpress, function

I get this error but unfortunately didn't know what is wrong with this code. Any ideas? I guess I need to make another else option to other shipping options?

```
    function action_woocommerce_email_order_details( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ) {
// Target specific email notification
if ( $email->id == 'customer_completed_order' ) {
    // Get order id
    $order_id = $order->get_id();
    $shipping_items      = $order->get_items( 'shipping' );
    $shipping_item       = reset( $shipping_items );
    $shipping_method_id  = $shipping_item->get_method_id() . ':';
    $shipping_method_id .= $shipping_item->get_instance_id();
    $pristatysimePatys = get_field('pristatysime_patys', $order_id);
    // Get order notes
    $order_notes = wc_get_order_notes( array(
        'order_id'  => $order_id,
        'order_by'  => 'date_created',
        'order'     => 'ASC',
    ));

    if($pristatysimePatys) {
        echo '<p>Jūsų užsakymas nr. ' . $order_id . ' perduotas kurjeriui.</p>';
    }
    
    if ( $shipping_method_id == 'local_pickup:27' ) {
        echo '<p>Sveiki, Jūsų užsakymas nr. ' . $order_id . ' yra suruoštas. Kviečiame atsiimti adresu:   Rudens g. 29, Neveronys. www.sodoroze.lt</p>';
    } elseif ( ! empty( $order_notes ) ) {
        foreach ( $order_notes as $order_note ) {
            if ( strpos( $order_note->content, 'DPD siuntos numeris' ) !== false ) {
                echo '<p>Jūsų užsakymas nr. ' . $order_id . ' perduotas kurjeriui. ' . $order_note->content . '</p>';
            }
        }
    }
}}
```

Comment: It means that your `$shipping_item` variable at this point is not a class instance, but only a boolean containing true or false. `reset`, quote manual, _"Returns the value of the first array element, or false if the array is empty."_ So you should implement a proper check whether you actually _have_ any shipping methods at this point.

Comment: @CBroe thanks for your answer. Maybe you have idea how I can do that?

Comment: `$order->get_items( 'shipping' );` has likely simply returned an empty array at this point (otherwise, `reset` should have thrown an error already), so just use `count` to check if the number of elements is > 0. Set the `$shipping_method_id` to null or an empty string then, so that it goes into the elseif branch at the end (or whatever meets your actual requirements, for orders that do not have any shipping method.)